# How to respond to interview questions for infosec position?

Tags: career

I have applied for an infosec internship with a company and they sent me a reply email asking me to answer a specific question.

They want me to draw a network diagram with specific components and properties (web server vulnerable to a privilege escalation attack).

The problem is I am a CS major. I had a couple IT courses at my last college, but I have not practiced those skills in years and I cannot call on them. I have a general idea of what to do but that is it. My experience is primarily with code and math.

I was expecting something like "What if a buffer overflow" or "How can you mitigate a SYN flood?".

I am worried that if I somehow manage to make it past this stage, I will be asked more specific IT-type questions that I have few answers to.

This is the kind of job I'd really like. Unfortunately I have little experience with security things. I have read most of a book on hacking (my ultimate aspiration being a pen tester) but to practice some of these skills, I have avoided. I'd rather not do something that might get me in trouble.

Comment: what is your question? you respond by answering the question ...

Comment: There are many different types of infosec, application security is only one of them. If you want to be a pentester, then their question is perfectly valid.  Are you sure that you are applying for the correct internship?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that they are actually looking for someone with more hands-on IT knowledge and less of a computer scientist?

Comment: This is a discussion type question, not suited for forums like this one. r/netsecstudents is likely a better fit for your kind of question.

Comment: For the record, that doesn't sound like a question for an intern, but for an architect...

Comment: Y'all are retarded.

Answer (score 2):

You're applying for an internship. Having a working knowledge of the subject matter is only a bonus.

As with any interviewing process, even if you can't solve the problem, try. Inexperience is to be expected from interns, so if you can at least show what you *do* know about the problem and how you might go about solving it *while knowing nothing about it*, it's often more important than how you'd respond to textbook questions. Everybody already knows what a buffer overflow is and nobody gives a damn about how you'd mitigate a SYN flood-- chances are they've already bought an appliance that will do it without your assistance.

But how well can you respond to things you've never seen before? That's the true test of your worth to an employer.

> but to practice some of these skills, I have avoided. I'd rather not do something that might get me in trouble.

This is not a good excuse, especially with the plethora of free virtualization software on the market for you to test any theory in any environment on your own equipment.

Literally the only rule you need to follow is **don't practice on other people's stuff.**

Answer (score 1):

> I have applied for an infosec internship with a company

Congratualations on taking the first step towards the career of your choice.

> They want me to draw a network diagram with specific components and
>   properties (web server vulnerable to a privilege escalation attack).

This is not unheard of for an information security position. Security touches upon many subjects and areas related to digital devices and networks and to be successful, you do need a good understanding of all of these areas. I do not know your current level of knowledge but I would recommend getting familiar with CISSP course structure and touching upon each of the domains so you know, and are better prepared for, what to expect during security interviews.

> I was expecting something like "What if a buffer overflow" or "How can
>   you mitigate a SYN flood?".

Those questions can be expected but sometimes questions are more indirectly related to security as the one they asked you. You should be prepared for them as well -- again, take a look at CISSP course structure to understand what to expect in general. For instance, a buffer overflow could only be well-understood if you understand how programs execute in memory. So it is valid you ask questions about memory management and registers in a computer. So yes, you will likely be asked more IT related specific questions.

> This is the kind of job I'd really like. Unfortunately I have little
>   experience with security things. I have read most of a book on hacking

No one book will give you all the information and experience you need for penetration testing. It comes with time, patience, perseverance and a *lot* of reading.

Goodluck!